# How to report an error in Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I am writing a program that returns every rth element from a list. The list can be any type. I want to report an error when r is zero but my code isn't working (it is working fine when I comment out the error line). Can anyone tell me how to report an error in this situation

```
rthElem :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rthElem _ [] = []
rthElem 0 (x:xs) = "Error"
rthElem n (x:xs) = rthElem' n 1 (x:xs) where
    rthElem' n i (x:xs)  = (if (n `divides` i) then
        [x] else
        [])
        ++ (rthElem' n (i+1) xs)
    rthElem' _ _ [] = []
    divides x y = y `mod` x == 0
```

Comment: What is your intention with the reported error?  Do you want to abort the program or do you want to handle the error gracefully and recover execution?

Comment: Usually if the function is not total, you make the result `Maybe a`, or `Either String a`, where you return `Left "some error message", or `Right answer`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Maybe` or `Either` in this case.

This is how `Maybe` looks. `Nothing` will be our "error".

```
rthElem :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
rthElem _ [] = Just []
rthElem 0 (x:xs) = Nothing
rthElem n (x:xs) = Just (rthElem' n 1 (x:xs)) where
    rthElem' n i (x:xs)  = (if (n `divides` i) then
        [x] else
        [])
        ++ (rthElem' n (i+1) xs)
    rthElem' _ _ [] = []
    divides x y = y `mod` x == 0

main :: IO ()
main = case (rthElem 0 [1..5]) of
  Nothing  -> putStrLn "Error"
  Just elm -> print elm
```

Another way is using `Either`. `Either` will return `Left` or `Right`. `Left` will be our "error".

```
rthElem :: Int -> [a] -> Either String [a]
rthElem _ [] = Right []
rthElem 0 (x:xs) = Left "Error"
rthElem n (x:xs) = Right (rthElem' n 1 (x:xs)) where
    rthElem' n i (x:xs)  = (if (n `divides` i) then
        [x] else
        [])
        ++ (rthElem' n (i+1) xs)
    rthElem' _ _ [] = []
    divides x y = y `mod` x == 0

main :: IO ()
main = case (rthElem 0 [1..5]) of
  Left err  -> putStrLn err
  Right elm -> print elm
```

The best way is using `Either`. Read more about error handling [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/10_Error_Handling).

Comment: Usually, instead of `print string` it is better to use `putStrLn string`, since the former will add quoting/escaping to the string. Instead, `print elm` is fine.

Comment: @chi Okay, I'm with you. Editted~

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to print an error and show it you could use the error function, `error :: String -> a`

```
rthElem 0 (x:xs) = error "Error msg here"
```

But there is a plenty better ways to do this , and you should figure out which one fits in your case , you can use Maybe, Either even monads , here is an interesting link with examples http://www.randomhacks.net/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors/

Answer (score 0):

You could use exceptions but you'd also have to transform your function into an IO action.

```
rthElem :: Int -> [a] -> IO [a]
rthElem _ [] = return []
rthElem 0 _ = ioError $ userError "Error"
rthElem n l = return $ rthElem' n 1 l where
    rthElem' n i (x:xs)  = (if (n `divides` i) then
        [x] else
        [])
        ++ (rthElem' n (i+1) xs)
    rthElem' _ _ [] = []
    divides x y = y `mod` x == 0
```

Comment: Please do not turn otherwise pure functions into having IO results just because you want to report an error.

Comment: @kosmikus I'm not saying that this is a good idea.  Clearly the `Maybe` solution is the preferred one.  I just wanted to show what is available.